# handsontable - bootstrap fixed top navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, handsontable

Is there anyway to make `handsontable` to work with `bootstrap fixed top navbar`?

I tried something like this:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

<div id="sheet"></div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When I scroll down, the table header will move to top and stay there, which covers the fixed-top navbar.

How can I make handsontable header to fix to 50px from top? So that, both bootstrap fixed-top navbar and handsontable header will work at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry that I cannot provide more help than this, but if you look at their javascript code on their repository, you will find functions they are using to fix it to the top of the page, which will overwrite any css classes that you apply to html elements. [handsontable js code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/handsontable/handsontable/master/dist/handsontable.full.js). You can go here and search for keywords such as scroll, offset, getWindowScrollTop, etc to see what they are doing.

Comment: @KurtKing, thanks! the code seems complicated, i don't want to modify it, for now, i'm using fixed-bottom navbar, this has no conflict with handsontable